# Qlikview Timestamp formatting upto microseconds?

Tags: qlikview

In qlikview I can get timestamp in milliseconds, by setting timestamp format as :-

```
SET TimestampFormat='MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss.fff';
```

I want to know if there is a way to get time stamp in qlikview upto microseconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formula to optain microseconds from TimeField:

```
((frac(TimeField) * 86400000) - floor(frac(TimeField) * 86400000)) * 1000 as Micro
```

And I would use this formula for formatting:

```
Timestamp(TimeField - (Micro/86400000000)) & Num(floor(Micro), '000') as TimeStamp
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can determine from the QlikView help, there is no format specifier for microseconds, only for milliseconds.

If you need to obtain the microsecond value from a time, I quickly threw the below together (it can probably be done a bit neater). Here I assume your input time field is called `TimeField`. We can obtain the number of milliseconds using:

```
=((TimeField-num(date(floor(TimeField)))-
num(maketime(hour(TimeField),minute(TimeField),second(TimeField))))*24*60*60)*1000
```

For the sake of simplicity, I will call the above formula `MillisecondCount`. Then, using this field, we can then calculate the number of microseconds:

```
=floor(((MillisecondCount)-floor(MillisecondCount))*1000)
```

Finally, the full formula to obtain microseconds becomes:

```
floor(((((TimeField-num(date(floor(TimeField)))-
num(maketime(hour(TimeField),minute(TimeField),second(TimeField))))*24*60*60)*1000)
-floor(((TimeField-num(date(floor(TimeField)))-
num(maketime(hour(TimeField),minute(TimeField),second(TimeField))))*24*60*60)*1000))*1000)
```

You can then just format this with `num()` and append it to your time-stamp string.